# Wrong file format

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera, flume-ng

I am working in Cloudera and have just started to learn it. So I have been trying to implement a famous twitter example with flume. With efforts, I have been able to stream the data from Twitter and now it is being saved in a file. After I have got the data now I want to perform analysis on Twitter data. But the issue is I cannot get the twitter data in the table. I have successfully created the **"tweets"** table but cannot load the data in the table.
Below I have given Twitter.conf file, external table creation query, data load query, error message and some chunk of the data I have got. Kindly guide me where I am doing wrong. Please note I have been writing the queries in HIVE editor.

**Twitter.conf file**

```
# Naming the components on the current agent. 
TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter 
TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel 
TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

# Describing/Configuring the source 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = 95y0IPClnNPUTJ1AHSfvBLWes
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = UmlNcFwiBIQIvuHF9J3M3xUv6UmJlQI3RZWT8ybF2KaKcDcAw5
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = 994845066882699264-Yk0DNFQ4VJec9AaCQ7QTBlHldK5BSK1 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret =  q1Am5G3QW4Ic7VBx6qJg0Iv7QXfk0rlDSrJi1qDjmY3mW
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, big data, analytics, bigdata, cloudera, data science, data scientiest, business intelligence, mapreduce, data warehouse, data warehousing, mahout, hbase, nosql, newsql, businessintelligence, cloudcomputing



# Describing/Configuring the channel 
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory 
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000 
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100

# Binding the source and sink to the channel 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel 

# Describing/Configuring the sink 

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = /user/cloudera/latestdata/
TwitterAgent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1000
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10000
```

External table query and load data in table query

```
CREATE External  TABLE tweets (


id BIGINT,
   created_at STRING,
   source STRING,
   favorited BOOLEAN,
   retweet_count INT,
   retweeted_status STRUCT<
     text:STRING,
     user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
   entities STRUCT<
     urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
     user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
     hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
   text STRING,
   user STRUCT<
     screen_name:STRING,
     name:STRING,
     friends_count:INT,
     followers_count:INT,
     statuses_count:INT,
     verified:BOOLEAN,
     utc_offset:INT,
     time_zone:STRING>,
   in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
 ) 
 PARTITIONED BY (datehour INT)
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
 LOCATION '/user/cloudera/tweets';




LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/cloudera/latestdata/FlumeData.1540555155464'
INTO TABLE `default.tweets`
PARTITION (datehour='2013022516')
```

Error When I try to load data into the table

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 20013 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask. Wrong file format. Please check the file's format.

**twitter data file I got**

SEQ!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritableorg.apache.hadoop.io.Text� �����R�LX� }H�f�>(�H�Objavro.schema�
{"type":"record","name":"Doc","doc":"adoc","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"string"},{"name":"user_friends_count","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"user_location","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"user_description","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"user_statuses_count","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"user_followers_count","type":["int","null"]},{"name":"user_name","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"user_screen_name","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"created_at","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"text","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"retweet_count","type":["long","null"]},{"name":"retweeted","type":["boolean","null"]},{"name":"in_reply_to_user_id","type":["long","null"]},{"name":"source","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"in_reply_to_status_id","type":["long","null"]},{"name":"media_url_https","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"expanded_url","type":["string","null"]}]}�yږ���w����M߀J��&1055790978844540929����gracie owehimnothng(2018-10-26T04:59:19Z�GIRLS WE THROWING IT BACK FOR JOAN OF

It has been 1 week and not able to figure out what is the solution.
Please let me know if more information is needed I will provide it here.

Answer (score 0):

Flume is not writing JSON, so JSONSerde isn't what you want.

You'll need to adjust these lines

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.flumeHDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream 
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
```

Flume is currently writing Sequencefile containing Avro

`SEQ!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritableorg.apache.hadoop.io.Text� �����R�LX� }H�f�>(�H�Objavro.schema�`

And Hive can read Avro as-is, so it's not clear why you are using JSONSerde

Comment: can you tell me if how I can get flume to write in json?

Comment: Have you tried seeing what other values you can set for `hdfs.writeFormat` in the Flume documentation?